# How to connect the conversation service with the discovery service when the UI is FB messenger

Tags: facebook, watson-conversation, watson-discovery

I have made an watson conversation service on bluemix that is conected to FB messenger. I would like to connect this service to the watson discovery service I have created on Bluemix, without a third party UI app. Are there some middleware software I can deploy on bluemix to connect the 2 services? I am aware of the conversation-with discovery app, but I do not need an UI app (FB messenger is my UI), can this app still work as a pure middleware?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is best answered with a diagram. Your app doesn't need a UI, but you'll need it to handle some of the additional work.

[image]

In the diagram you can see I have an Application layer (NodeJS in this case). Your connection between Messenger and Watson Conversation would only have simplistic logic defined in the Watson Conversation tooling.

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate this architecture model. 1) I understand the Third-party API to be fir instance the Watson discovery service for long-tail more complex answers? 2) I already have a middel ware between watson conv and FB messenger (https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/botkit-middleware), do you suggest to expand this middelware with connection logic to Watson discovery as well? or 3) Can you provide me with an github link to an app that connects watson conv and watson discovery? Best regards Morten

Comment: Third Party in this instance means anything outside of the Watson Conversation service. So it could mean another service like Discovery, or one that site entirely outside of the IBM Cloud.

https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-with-discovery